# Bootstrap modal not working in 3.3.6

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

I have a simple page and a modal. This worked in a (much) older version of bootstrap, but since I upgraded to a newer version, it's "not working" anymore:

The page loads, then turns dark (all ok!), but the modal window does not come up at all and I can (therefor?) also not click out of it...

html of modal:

```
<div class="modal hide fade" id="myModal">
  <div class="modal-header" style="background:#f6b33d -moz-linear-gradient(center top , #f6b33d 5%, #d29105 100%) repeat scroll 0 0;">
    <a class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</a>
    <h3 style="color:#ffffff;">Please Note:</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <p>You can put whatever text you want in here... or form or whatever you want..</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

js:

```
$(window).load(function(){
   setTimeout(function(){
       $('#myModal').modal('show');
   }, 5000);
});
```

See http://codepen.io/Malachi/pen/bpLrPy

What am I missing??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove **hide** and add **div.modal-dialog** and **div.modal-content** (that's how modals work on bootstrap)

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header" style="background:#f6b33d -moz-linear-gradient(center top , #f6b33d 5%, #d29105 100%) repeat scroll 0 0;">
          <a class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</a>
          <h3 style="color:#ffffff;">Please Note:</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
           <p>You can put whatever text you want in here... or form or whatever you want..</p>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you are unsure check these examples from bootstrap site: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you don't use the `hide` class. The modal markup should be like this.

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header" style="background:#f6b33d -moz-linear-gradient(center top , #f6b33d 5%, #d29105 100%) repeat scroll 0 0;">
          <a class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</a>
          <h3 style="color:#ffffff;">Please Note:</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>You can put whatever text you want in here... or form or whatever you want..</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

http://bootply.com/14LH4kZul2